# Find updated files gradle --continuous build and filter out a specific directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy

I have a gradle task in my Spring boot project which depends on `build` task. The task is executed with `--continuous` option from terminal. Now I can trigger this task by updating any source file, because this watches for any source file changes.

```
gradle buildAndReload --continuous -x test // terminal command

tasks.register('buildAndReload') {         // gradle task in build.gradle
    dependsOn build
    mustRunAfter build
    doLast {
       // do something
    }    
}
```

But I don't want to "do something" when the change is only in a specific folder, say "src/main/java/com/example/dummy". If a file `src/main/java/com/example/dummy/Abc.java` is changed, I don't need to run this task or I don't need to perform operations inside `doLast`.

**First try**: Exclude `src/main/java/com/example/dummy` from `sourceSets`. But then the files in this folder won't be compiled in anyway. So this is not a solution.

**Second try**: Add below code inside `doLast`. But the `task.inputs.sourceFiles` not only includes the updated files, but also the other source files which are unchanged. So this is also not a solution.

```
doLast {
  boolean nonDummyFileChanged = task.inputs.sourceFiles.files.stream()
                .map { file -> file.name }
                .dropWhile { name -> name.contains("src/main/java/com/example/dummy") }
                .findAny()
                .isPresent()
  if (!nonDummyFileChanged) {
      System.out.println("Non dummy file hasn't changed. No need to run task")
      return
  }
  // do something
}
```

The task or `doLast` in the task should only run if there is a source change outside `src/main/java/com/example/dummy`. Please help!

Comment: Could to extract that the com/example/dummy from the source directories?  Maybe put it in its own source set separate from the main code base?

Comment: Thanks @chubbsondubs for the input. But, for some reason, we cannot change the directory structure.